# Why does just created android app take about 60-80Mb of RAM?

Tags: android, performance

today I realized that app I just created (It has only one Activity with text "Hello World!" and nothing - just standart blank android app) already takes about 60-80Mb of RAM. Can anyone tell me why does it happen? And how to reduce RAM usage of the android app in this case?

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: what kind of android app? Java, Kotlin, Flutter, React-Native, Cordova, or?

Comment: @PrafullaMalviya Here it is https://pastebin.com/wC6nedFE

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך Java

Comment: Making the hello world app doesn' mean the ram is goind to be 0mb.Also it doesn't mean if you add 15 more activities your ram usage will be 60*15 which is 900.It's the essential space for running an android app.After that it doesn't go so much up if you're careful what you're doing with memory mangement

Comment: @stevemoretz Thank you very much... I'm not so stupid. I was looking for reasons why app using so much RAM for that simple activity.
There is another detail. This app uses about 10-20mb on device with API 23 and 500mb RAM.

Comment: @unkownStudent I did not mean to offend you.Yeah on all apis you don't get the same results.It's like windows 8 and windows 10,windows 10 uses a lot more memory.Even though you may think it must use less because it's newer but it doesn't.